# Query to find circular references

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, cte, recursive

I have two tables

```
ID  Task
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4

Col1  depend
2     3
2     4
3     1
4     2
```

`ID` and `Col1` are related through FK constraint. I want to find out all circular references. Here `ID` and `Col1` is just for combining rows from 2 tables, e.g.:

```
Task 1 can start anytime.
Task 2 can start only after completion of 3, 4 etc

1 –
2 – 3, 4, 1, 2   -- for 2 there is circular dependency
3 – 1
4 – 2, 3, 4      -- also circular dependency
```

Case 2:

```
Col1  depend
2     3
2     4
3     1
4     5
5     2

ID  Task
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5

1
2 – 3, 4, 1, 5, 2     -- circular reference
3 – 1
4 – 5, 2, 3, 4        -- circular reference
5 – 2, 3, 4, 5        -- circular reference
```

Circular references may be available at any recursion level. How to find such circular references?
We have tried a recursive query but we went in infinite loop. How to write recursive query for this?

Comment: It's quite easy to prevent the infinite loop for a recursive query, but I have not found a way to actually mark a row as having a cycle (because the JOIN condition to prevent the loop will filter out the last element).

Answer (score 4):

I adapted the example at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html to your case:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(id, depends, depth, path, cycle) AS (
        SELECT g.Col1, g.depends, 1,
          ARRAY[g.Col1],
          false
        FROM deps g
      UNION ALL
        SELECT g.Col1, g.depends, sg.depth + 1,
          path || g.Col1,
          g.Col1 = ANY(path)
        FROM deps g, search_graph sg
        WHERE g.Col1 = sg.depends AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT distinct id FROM search_graph where cycle = true;
```

results:

```
ID
 4
 2
```

for the first example,

```
ID
 4
 2
 5
```

for the second

You can find the sql fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/87a96/2

Answer (score 3):

Also building on the [example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE graph AS (
   SELECT col1 AS id
        , ARRAY[depend, col1] AS path
        , (depend = col1) AS cycle    -- first step could be circular
   FROM   dep

   UNION ALL
   SELECT d.col1, d.depend || path, d.depend = ANY(path)
   FROM   graph g
   JOIN   dep   d ON d.col1 = g.path[1]
   WHERE  NOT g.cycle
   )
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM   graph
WHERE  cycle;
```

Result

```
id
 2
 4
 5
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a20ac/1)

This is a bit simpler and faster:

- No irrelevant columns.
- Needs one less iteration because it checks ahead.
- Identifies short-circuiting rows immediately. (It has not been ruled out that a row can link to itself.)

This one `prepends` the path with the respective new item, so we can use `path[1]` instead of an additional column. To my knowledge, just as fast as *appending* elements.
Accessing the first element of an array should be almost as cheap as an extra column - which would make the row wider. Test and compare if performance is important:

```
WITH RECURSIVE graph AS (
   SELECT col1 AS id, depend AS col1  -- simplify join condition
        , ARRAY[col1, depend] AS path
        , (col1 = depend) AS cycle    -- simplify if short-circuit impossible
   FROM   dep

   UNION ALL
   SELECT d.col1, d.depend
        , path || d.depend, d.depend = ANY(path)
   FROM   graph g
   JOIN   dep   d USING (col1)
   WHERE  NOT g.cycle
   )
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM   graph
WHERE  cycle;
```